# Issue with Redis setup cluster mode in docker(Windows 7)

Tags: java, docker, caching, redis, jedis

I am trying to set up Redis in cluster mode and when I try to connect to Redis using Jedis API, I am seeing below exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisNoReachableClusterNodeException: No reachable node in cluster
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.getConnection(JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.java:57)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.getConnectionFromSlot(JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.java:74)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:116)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.run(JedisClusterCommand.java:31)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster.set(JedisCluster.java:103)
    at com.redis.main.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

I am using below command to start the Redis

```
$ docker run -v /d/redis.conf:/usr/bin/redis.conf --name myredis redis redis-server /usr/bin/redis.conf
```

And my simple redis.conf looks like below.

```
port 6379
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.conf
cluster-node-timeout 5000
appendonly yes
```

And below are redis start up logs.

```
$ docker run -v /d/redis.conf:/usr/bin/redis.conf --name myredis redis redis-se
rver /usr/bin/redis.conf
1:C 11 Oct 18:06:01.657 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
1:C 11 Oct 18:06:01.663 # Redis version=4.0.2, bits=64, commit=00000000, modifi
d=0, pid=1, just started
1:C 11 Oct 18:06:01.664 # Configuration loaded
1:M 11 Oct 18:06:01.685 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
1:M 11 Oct 18:06:01.690 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enf
rced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
1:M 11 Oct 18:06:01.692 # Server initialized
1:M 11 Oct 18:06:01.696 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background sav
 may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memo
y = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overco
mit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
1:M 11 Oct 18:06:01.697 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support
enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with R
dis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent
hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain
he setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
1:M 11 Oct 18:06:01.700 * Ready to accept connections
```

And below is the simple java program.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<HostAndPort> jedisClusterNodes = new HashSet<HostAndPort>();
        jedisClusterNodes.add(new HostAndPort("127.0.0.1", 6379));
        JedisCluster jc = new JedisCluster(jedisClusterNodes);

        //Jedis jc = new Jedis("192.168.99.100");

        jc.set("prime", "1 is prime");
        String keyVal = jc.get("prime");
        System.out.println(keyVal);
    }
}
```

Not really sure what is going wrong here and will appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose the port when starting the redis container

```
docker run -v /d/redis.conf:/usr/bin/redis.conf -p 6379:6379 --name myredis redis redis-server /usr/bin/redis.conf
```

Comment: Now i see this exception "Exception in thread "main" redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR This instance has cluster support disabled"